# Web Scraper not getting the full data from a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib

I'm trying to scrape [this](https://www.eraktkosh.in/BLDAHIMS/bloodbank/campSchedule.cnt) website to prepare a database for blood donation camps using python.

Firstly, while trying to get the website html source code from requests or urllib there is a SSl:certificate_verify_error which i have bypassed by setting verify parameter as False for requests.get() or creating unverified context for urllib (a quick fix), this gets me past the error, but when i see the retrieved source html code, the table content that i need is empty, in website source they are included in the tbody tags but my requests.get() command gets me only these tags and not the content in between them. I'm very new to scraping, a little guidance would be appreciated. ty

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import ssl
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.eraktkosh.in/BLDAHIMS/bloodbank/campSchedule.cnt'
sp_context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
uClient = uReq(my_url,context=sp_context)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup=soup(page_html,"html.parser")
table = page_soup.find('tbody')
print (table) #this outputs "<tbody></tbody>"
trow = table.find('tr')
print (trow) #this outputs "None"
```

First print command gives

```html
<tbody>
</tbody>
```

and second outputs

```
None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is so because the first request returns an almost empty html scaffold.

The data you see on the page is being populated by subsequent ajax requests. This one to be exact https://www.eraktkosh.in/BLDAHIMS/bloodbank/nearbyBB.cnt?hmode=GETNEARBYCAMPS&stateCode=-1&districtCode=-1&_=1560150852947

You can retrieve this info by going to right click -> inspect -> networks tab and reloading the page.

Opinion: BeautifulSoup is not required for extracting information from this page. The data is readily available in json format from the API mentioned above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I have an additional question. I'm guessing almost all the sites would use something similar to the above method to retrieve data, then how does the method given in every web scraping tutorial have no mention of this and yet they manage to get the data in html format ?

Comment: Only the websites using JavaScript to render the data on client side need to be handled this way.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this HTTP call:

https://www.eraktkosh.in/BLDAHIMS/bloodbank/nearbyBB.cnt?hmode=GETNEARBYCAMPS&stateCode=-1&districtCode=-1&_=1560150750074

This is where the data come from.

You have 2 options:

1. Do the HTTP call and parse the response
2. Use headless browser and scrape the website. See [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/better-web-scraping-in-python-with-selenium-beautiful-soup-and-pandas-d6390592e251/).

Answer (score 0):

Using `pandas` library to save data into csv file.

In the browser `network` tab, you will see the `JSON data response` of `campSchedule` table data.

```
import requests
import  pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.eraktkosh.in/BLDAHIMS/bloodbank/nearbyBB.cnt?hmode=GETNEARBYCAMPS&stateCode=-1&districtCode=-1&_=1560150855565'
jsonData = requests.get(url, verify=False).json()

campScheduleData = []

for data in jsonData['data']:
    campSchedule = {"Date":"","Time":"","Camp Name":"","Address":"","State":"","District":"",\
                    "Contact":"","Conducted By":"","Organized by":"","Register":""}
    if "<br/>" in data[1]:
        campSchedule['Date'] = data[1].split("<br/>")[0]

    if "href" in data[10]:
        campSchedule['Register'] = "https://www.eraktkosh.in" + data[10].split("href=")[1].split(" ")[0]

    campSchedule['Time'] = data[2]
    campSchedule['Camp Name'] = data[3]
    campSchedule['Address'] = data[4]
    campSchedule['State'] = data[5]
    campSchedule['District'] = data[6]
    campSchedule['Contact'] = data[7]
    campSchedule['Conducted By'] = data[8]
    campSchedule['Organized by'] = data[9]
    campScheduleData.append(campSchedule)

df = pd.DataFrame(campScheduleData)
# it will save csv file in current project directory with campScheduleData.csv file name
df.to_csv("campSchedule.csv")
```

If you not install pandas, install it:

```
pip3 install pandas
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas and re

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import urllib3; urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
import re

p1 = re.compile(r"(.*?)<br/>")
p2 = re.compile(r"href='(.*?)'")

def get_url(html, p): 
    if html == 'NA':
        url = html
    else:
        url = 'https://www.eraktkosh.in' + p.findall(html)[0]
    return url

def get_date(html, p): 
    if html == 'NA':
        date_string = html
    else:
        date_string = p.findall(html)[0]
    return date_string

r = requests.get('https://www.eraktkosh.in/BLDAHIMS/bloodbank/nearbyBB.cnt?hmode=GETNEARBYCAMPS&stateCode=-1&districtCode=-1&_=1560150750074', verify = False).json()
df = pd.DataFrame(r['data'])
df[1] = df[1].apply(lambda x: get_date(x, p1))
df[10] = df[10].apply(lambda x: get_url(x, p2))
print(df)
```